# Array function with using Unique not working

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, unique

[image]

Any input would be appreciated

Not expecting error - google mentioned different number of rows in arguments?

Comment: Why do you need to wrap it with "ARRAYFORMULA"? looks like you only care about printing NEW/OLD in that column, no?

Comment: Please fix the tags. Excel <> Google Sheets

Comment: A bit confused as to who im replying to here, but here goes...
Nir : Yes, that is all I want :) I thought arrayformula got rid of the need to keep copying formula down - thanks for your response.

Comment: jvdV : thanks for your response . not sure whats wrong with the tags. It has nothing to do with excel + google sheets is tagged. If im doing something wrong pls let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

Well if your goal is to label the first instance of an ID as `NEW` and any subsequent repetitions of the same ID as `OLD`, then you may try this:

```
=map(L2:L,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,if(countif(L2:Σ,Σ)=1,"NEW","OLD"))))
```

[image]

Comment: WOW - I have no clue what that formula says/does but it works :) thanks so much.
You sure its not sending you my keystorokes? lol